# Как задать порядок cardviews в recyclerview?

Tags: android

По задумке порядок карточек в RecyclerView такой:
header,
product,
header2,
product 
и т.д.
Но в результате получается:
header,
header2,
product(все карточки вперемешку). А мне нужно, чтобы они шли по-порядку.

Код:

```
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {

public static RequestInterface requestInterface;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Object> items;


public ShopFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);

    requestInterface = Controller.getApi();

    items = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_recycle_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Header header = new Header();
    header.setHeader("Leggins");
    items.add(header);

        requestInterface.getProduct(11).enqueue(new Callback <Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Product> call, Response <Product> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "данные пришли", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                items.add(response.body());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <Product> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    Header header2 = new Header();
    header2.setHeader("Mats");
    items.add(header2);

        requestInterface.getProduct(75).enqueue(new Callback <Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Product> call, Response <Product> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "данные пришли", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                items.add(response.body());
                response.errorBody();
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <Product> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

}

Код адаптера:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    public List<Object> items;

    private final int PRODUCT = 0, HEADER = 1;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Object> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (items.get(position) instanceof Product) {
            return PRODUCT;
        }
        if (items.get(position) instanceof Header) {
            return HEADER;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        switch (viewType) {
            case PRODUCT:
                View v1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false);
                vh = new ProductViewHolder(v1);
                break;
            case HEADER:
                View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_item, parent, false);
                vh = new HeaderViewHolder(v2);
                break;
            default:
                View v3 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false);
                vh = new ProductViewHolder(v3);

        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (this.getItemViewType(position)) {
            case PRODUCT:
                final ProductViewHolder productViewHolder = (ProductViewHolder) holder;
                final Product product = (Product) items.get(position);
                productViewHolder.title.setText(product.getTitle());
                productViewHolder.price.setText("$" + String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
                productViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, YogaLeggins.class));
                    }
                });
                break;
            case HEADER:
                Header header = (Header) items.get(position);
                HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
                headerViewHolder.header.setText(header.getHeader());
                break;
        }
    }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (items == null)
                return 0;
            return items.size();
        }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView price;
        CardView cardView;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        }
    }

    class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView header;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запрос в сеть асинхронный - его результат добавляется когда-нибудь потом, тогда как хедеры вставляются сразу. Варианты: добавлять хедер в `onResponse`, либо получить все данные разом и потом сформировать список.

Comment: woesss, а как осуществить второй вариант?

Comment: Тут используется retrofit для получения данных?

Comment: SpKiwi, да, retrofit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечая на первую часть вопроса: для того, чтобы выполнять запросы в строго определенном порядке без лишней сложности можно вместо метода ретрофита `enqueue` использовать `execute`. Тогда после двух последовательных вызовов метода `execute` можно будет получить полностью сформированную коллекцию элементов. Одно но: не выполняйте метод `execute` в главном потоке приложения.

Для сортировки внутри адаптера я бы реализовал метод `getItemViewType` и видоизменил бы `onCreateViewHolder` соответствующим образом. Выглядеть это будет приблизительно так:

```
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 1;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_PRODUCT = 2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 == 0 ? ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER : ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_PRODUCT ;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (layoutInflater == null) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    }

    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER :
            return new ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_header, parent, false));

        case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_PRODUCT :
            return new ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_product, parent, false));
    }
    return new ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_header, parent, false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Порядок следования итемов определяется вашим адаптеров - в данном случае вашим классом `ProductAdapter` - вы передаете туда `List` со своими итемами.

Вам нужно организовать сортировку списка итемов в `ProductAdapter`, реализовав например интерфейс `Comparable`, для чего можно было бы написать классик описывающий ваш итем в виде:

```
public class MyItem implements Comparable {
   //blah-blah
}
```

и передавать в адаптер список в виде `List<MyItem>`

Надеюсь изложил понятно.

**Update**

Попробуем написать так:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
   List<MyItem> items;

   public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<MyItem> items) {
       this.context = context;
       Collections.sort(items); //сортируем при создании
       this.items=items;
    }    

    //надо не забывать сортировать еще и при добавлении новых записей
}


class MyItem implements Comparable {
    Object object;
    public Object getItem();

    //примитивный компаратор который выводит вперед Header, а Product опускает вниз
    int compareTo(MyItem myItem) {
       if(object instanceof Header && myItem.getObject() instanceof Product)
          return 1;
       else if(object instanceof Header && myItem.getObject() instanceof Header)
          return 0;
       else if(object instanceof Product && myItem.getObject() instanceof Header)
          return -1;
       else if {
           //blah-blah логика для Header2 и проч.
       }
       else
          return 0;
    }
}
```

P.S. Мне самому дико не нравятся эти `instanceof`, но как говорится следовал вашей логике.

Comment: Barmaley, не особо понимаю как это применить к коду моего адаптера

Comment: см. апдейт ответа